# Ubuntu keeps crashing when using VSCode and Firefox

Tags: firefox, freeze, visual-studio-code

Ubuntu 22.04 keeps crashing and freezing mostly when I'm using my web browser and VSCode and Android emulator.

I've tried updating it, but the problem persists. Details about my PC are shown here:

[image: About my PC]

Comment: Does your computer have a GPU, either integrated graphics or a graphics card? If so, what model is the GPU?

Comment: Hello @karel here is it: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: Okay. Any suggestions on what I can do to stop it from hanging?

Comment: [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4408/)

Comment: I've been experiencing similar issues without the Android emulator. I'll just be running VSCode in the background, then Firefox slows down, VSCode crashes and then Firefox behaves normally.  Ubuntu 22.04.1 on a Dell XPS 13.